# What is the JavaScript equivalent of CURLOPT_REFERER in PHP when making a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, php, referer

I want to make a request to https://auth.roblox.com/v1/authentication-ticket with the referer as https://www.roblox.com/home. How would I add the referer parameter to the fetch request?

```
  const cookie = "cookie";
  const csrf = "assuming we have csrf ticket already";
  const gticket = await fetch(
    "https://auth.roblox.com/v1/authentication-ticket",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Cookie: ".ROBLOSECURITY=" + cookie,
        "x-csrf-token": csrf,
      },
      referrer: "https://www.roblox.com/home"
    }
  );
  const ticket = await gticket.text(); // error debugging
  console.log(ticket);
```

I tried the code above but it did not work. Please help me resolve this issue.

**{"errors":[{"code":2,"message":"The UrlReferrer was invalid or came from outside Roblox.","userFacingMessage":"Something went wrong"}]}**

Comment: @JaromandaX it's backend javascript

Comment: The HTTP header is `referer` not `referrer` (unfortunately the typo was not caught before it became the standard). It also needs to go under the `headers` object.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add this header to the request:

```
"Referer": "https://www.roblox.com/home"
```

Comment: Only that [referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) is a forbidden header name.